# R: Paste together some string vector elements based on list of indexes

Tags: r, string, vector, indexing

I have a string vector like this:

```
x <- c("ermanaric cayce nonwashable climactical outseeing dorr nubble",
       "aver unsegregating preprofess lumme noontime triskele",
       "riverbank walachian penza",
       "schlieren calthrop",
       "hutlike paraphyllium unservile chaplainship bordelaise",
       "phlogotic strategics jowlier orthopaedic nonprofiteering",
       "vizir rudenture shopkeeper",
       "interestuarine sardis",
       "anthas figuring",
       "unphased engle german emporium organometallic didy uneclipsing",
       "bronzy conant reballot",
       "extrados facinorous acrolithic",
       "paralyzation uningratiating enzymatically enuresis",
       "unscholastic extemporarily",
       "discipleship fossilize summae",
       "concretize intercharge palpate gombroon initiatrices",
       "intimation progressiveness",
       "unpictorialise",
       "romanticization",
       "wynnewood",
       "unmate libratory polysynthetic")
```

Some of the elements need to be pasted together to form longer strings. I have a list of vectors that contains indexes of the elements that have to be pasted together:

```
indx <- list(c(3, 4), c(7, 8, 9), c(11, 12), c(14, 15), c(17, 18, 19, 20))
```

That is, the 3rd and the 4th element have to be pasted together to form the string `"riverbank walachian penza schlieren calthrop"`, the 7th, 8th and 9th string to be pasted together to form the string `"vizir rudenture shopkeeper interestuarine sardis anthas figuring"` and so on (**EDIT**), keeping the rest of the strings in the same order. The resulting vector of strings would look like this:

```
y <- c("ermanaric cayce nonwashable climactical outseeing dorr nubble",
       "aver unsegregating preprofess lumme noontime triskele",
       "riverbank walachian penza schlieren calthrop",
       "hutlike paraphyllium unservile chaplainship bordelaise",
       "phlogotic strategics jowlier orthopaedic nonprofiteering",
       "vizir rudenture shopkeeper interestuarine sardis anthas figuring",
       "unphased engle german emporium organometallic didy uneclipsing",
       "bronzy conant reballot extrados facinorous acrolithic",
       "paralyzation uningratiating enzymatically enuresis",
       "unscholastic extemporarily discipleship fossilize summae",
       "concretize intercharge palpate gombroon initiatrices",
       "intimation progressiveness unpictorialise romanticization wynnewood",
       "unmate libratory polysynthetic")
```

I tried the following without any success:

```
myfun <- function(obj, indx) {
  paste(obj)[length(indx)]
}

mapply(myfun, x, m)
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that `indx` does not contain an entry for each item in `x` but you want each returned or merged somewhere makes this a bit more challenging.

One idea would be to successively update with `Reduce`, using temporary `NA`s to maintain the correspondence with index numbers.

```
my.y<-c(na.omit(Reduce(function(s,i) 
  replace(s,i,c(paste(s[i],collapse=" "),rep(NA,length(i)-1))),indx,x)))

identical(my.y,y)
#> [1] TRUE
```

Matches the desired output.

Comment: Works like charm! Thank you very much, also for the hint about `Reduce`.

Answer (score 2):

```
indx2 <- sapply(indx, '[', 1)
x[indx2] <- Map(function(x,y) paste(x[y], collapse=" "), list(x), indx)
unlist(x[sort(c(setdiff(seq_along(x), unlist(indx)),indx2))])
#  [1] "ermanaric cayce nonwashable climactical outseeing dorr nubble"      
#  [2] "aver unsegregating preprofess lumme noontime triskele"              
#  [3] "riverbank walachian penza schlieren calthrop"                       
#  [4] "hutlike paraphyllium unservile chaplainship bordelaise"             
#  [5] "phlogotic strategics jowlier orthopaedic nonprofiteering"           
#  [6] "vizir rudenture shopkeeper interestuarine sardis anthas figuring"   
#  [7] "unphased engle german emporium organometallic didy uneclipsing"     
#  [8] "bronzy conant reballot extrados facinorous acrolithic"              
#  [9] "paralyzation uningratiating enzymatically enuresis"                 
# [10] "unscholastic extemporarily discipleship fossilize summae"           
# [11] "concretize intercharge palpate gombroon initiatrices"               
# [12] "intimation progressiveness unpictorialise romanticization wynnewood"
# [13] "unmate libratory polysynthetic"
```

Comment: Nice, but this doesn't return the items of x that aren't supposed to be merged with any other items

Comment: The pasted strings appear above all else, i.e. the original sorting is lost. Otherwise works perfect. Thank you.

Comment: @panman I'm not sure what you mean, the output is exactly the same as the desired output. No?

Comment: @ Pierre: Sorry, I messed it up here, cleaned the workspace and ran it again. Works perfectly, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
indx <- list(c(3, 4), c(7, 8, 9), c(11, 12), c(14, 15), c(17, 18, 19, 20))
indx1 <- c(lapply(setdiff(1:length(x),unlist(indx)),c),indx)

indx2 <- indx1[order(sapply(indx1,"[[",1))]

sapply(indx2,function(z) {paste(x[z],collapse = " ")})
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This does the work of pasting the elements that are indexed, but does not return the rest of the vector. Works nice otherwise.

Comment: It was not obvious from the question that the remaining ones were also needed and in that order. Its fixed now. Its very similar to the other answer posted.

Comment: You are right, I did not say that. I fixed it. Thank you!